# How to get MVC action to return erroneous status

Tags: json, error-handling

Here is my scenario, I fetch the data from the database, try/catch it in the controller action and would  like to pass the code and the error message back to my js.

```
    //in my action

    [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult GetWorkorderDetails(string folderno)
 {   
    try{
    //do some stuff - fetch the data

    }catch() {
    //if error, I would like to set the JsonResult to return bad status and error message
    }
  }

    //in my js
    if(response.status == 400){
       //if error, output the message response.responseText and return
    }
```

Any way to set my response status to 400 inside the action in the catch statement?

Comment: try smth. like `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "Exception occured");`

Comment: Hi, can you post your comment as answer please?

Answer (score 1):

I would change return type to generic ActionResult and when needed return new HttpStatusCodeResult.